# Can I omit "which was"?

Tags: grammar, modifiers

In this sentence, can I omit "which was"?

"Leaning forward, he looked at his right hand, **which was** wrapped in thick, white bandages."

Comment: Or would it be better to rewrite the sentence as: "Learning forward, he looked at the thick, white bandages wrapped around his right hand."?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing 'which was' doesn't change the meaning. Moreover, it makes the sentence construction tidy. So, it can be omitted.

Comment: So what is the rule of thumb that would make sure we stay grammatically correct in addition to theneed to stay true to the meaning.

Comment: For instance, in the sentence:  "... one finds relationship A, which is a generalization of relationship B."    Could we instead say: "... one finds relationship A, a generalization of relationship B."    Seems to me like this somehow doesn't work, but an em-dash would make it work?

Comment: ... disseminating secret information (which was) sensitive to national security.